# C/C++ with Android Studio version 2.2

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio

With Android Studio 2.2, and the new C++ support they added; can I now write and compile inside android studio, or do I need to compile and import my libraries separately

Comment: Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html)

Comment: Ok.  I usually just use java for android projects, but got SUPER excited when I saw clang++ getting added during updates.  I've been using C++ for a few years, whereas java is fairly new to me.  If I'm reading your link right, it is saying that while support exists; for something minor I'm better off using java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

Here is what you can do [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM1sL.png)
1) In Android Studio, right click on your module ==> New ==> Package
2) name the package (folder) `cpp`  (or you can name it `jni`)
3) you will see the `cpp` directory on the left.
4) You can create `.cpp`, `.h` and other files within that folder.

[image: image #1]

Nowm you have to tell `gradle` how to build that.
You need install `CMake`.  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPkxI.png)
1) Go to Preferences ==> Android SDK ==> SDK Tools ==> CMake
2) Select that and click Apply and Ok

[image: CMake Install]

Now, you need to add a `CMakeLists.txt` file to your project.
Path: `my_project/app/CMakeLists.txt`

This is what the file should look like:

```
# https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script


# Minimum version of CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# adding CEC library
# add_library structure:    add_library(lib_name  lib_type_STATIC_or_SHARED  source_file_path)
add_library(my_lib_name SHARED src/main/jni/my_cpp_file.cpp)


# include_directories is to provide the path to you native lib code
# include_directories structure:    include_directories(native_lib_folder_path)
include_directories(src/main/jni/)


# adding Android log library
# find_library is used to find NDK API libraries (built in NDK libs)
# find_library structure:   find_library(name_you_want_to_call_the_lib  lib_name_in_ndk_api)
find_library(log-lib log)


# linking log lib to our native lib
# once you find the library, you have to link that library with your native library
# target_link_libraries structure:  target_link_libraries(you_native_lib  lib_found_using_find_library)
target_link_libraries(my_lib_name ${log-lib})
```

And final step: add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

You should be able to build it now.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi! @th3pat3I can you help me solve this please? As it seems you have more knowledge about NDK. Really appreciate if I get your help on  this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44281689/1468354

Comment: @THEPATEL I have around 8 .cpp files so do I need to include all of them in CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

th3pat3l's answer is works fine, but the official documentation for how to add C++ to a project is a little different. Here it is:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-sources

The main difference is the use of file->new->package. The package concept is for adding a java package and has a side effect of creating a folder.

You can do the same thing more directly by switching to project view and just creating the folder where you want it in the directory.