# Using .so file in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415510/import-existing-c-library-a-or-so-file-ndk-android) for guidance, I was able to successfully build my project with a C++ `.so` file in the `libs` directory.

However, I am not sure how to actually use it from `MainActivity.kt`.

The C++ class I'm using is `Number`:

```cpp
class Number {
    int number;
public:
    Number(int n) { number = n };
    bool isEven() { return number % 2 == 0 };
};
```

Assuming I've added the shared library file correctly, how do I actually use it?

Comment: You can only call C++ functions that have been exported and named in a certain way. And interacting with non-primitive C++ types can be done in more than one way. I suggest that you search for some kind of JNI tutorial since this is a bit of broad topic.